# why do I have to use group by here?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to solve this rank scores problem in leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/rank-scores/
and I have two solutions (mysql). Both work.

```
select a.Score as Score,
(select count(distinct b.Score) from Scores as b where b.Score>=a.score) as Rank
from Scores as a
order by a.Score desc;
```

and

```
select s1.Score,count(distinct(s2.score)) Rank
from
Scores s1,Scores s2
where
s1.score<=s2.score
group by s1.Id
order by Rank
```

But I am not sure why I have to use GROUP BY in solution two to make sure that sql calculate the count for each score (or else it returns the minimum score only), but I do not have to use it in solution one.

Comment: 'If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I am not sure why I have to use GROUP BY in solution two to make sure that sql calculate the count for each score

The second query works by self-joining the table on an inequality condition: for each row in alias `s1`, you get all rows in `s2` that have a smaller or equal score. You then need to aggregate so you can count how many `s2` rows there are for each `s1`, which gives you the rank.

Note: if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this without a join or subquery, using window function `rank()`, that does exactly what you want:

```
 select score, rank() over(order by score desc) rn from scores
```

Finally: as of 2020, you should be using *explicit*, standard joins rather than old-school, implicit joins:

```
select s1.score, count(distinct(s2.score)) rn
from scores s1
inner join scores s2 on s1.score <= s2.score
group by s1.id, s1.score
order by rn
```

Answer (score 2):

**Every column that is not a part of aggregation fucntion and it is in select clause needs to be added in the group by clause**

So for example:

Needs group by:

```
select col1, col2, count(*) -- count is aggregate function
from table_name
group by col1, col2
```

Or

Does not need group by:

```
select count(*) -- count is aggregate function
from table_name
```

Here is a small example to see how it works: [click HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c5a2aa059da9c4efa69ca272d7635d8)

---

Having that said yor second query does not work:
This is the code that works(is without errors):

```
select s1.Score
       , count(distinct(s2.score)) `Rank`
from Scores s1
join Scores s2 on s2.Score >= s1.score
group by s1.Score, s1.id
order by `Rank`;
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39b836ca1f0cdb9040fe0afcc3c06dea)